# Infrared diode, phototransistor, and multimeter

Tags: multimeter, infrared, phototransistor

I thought of creating a circuit for a light barrier. I got the required components: an IR LED diode, an IR phototransistor, an op-amp, a potentiometer, a blue LED, and resistors.
After much testing and re-building I came up with this circuit which works well enough:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCt7gd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Until I removed the multimeter I used for testing. After that, the phototransistor stopped turning on the LED when the beam of light from the IR LED was interrupted.

I thought the multimeter took some current from the circuit, and moved the threshold for the LED to turn on. I rotated the potentiometer to both sides (moved a few hundred millivolts and interrupted the light barrier, and then moved again) and the LED stayed either on or off, not changing its state when the beam was interrupted.

I can't test this unknown state, because when I plug in the multimeter it works again. I can't have a multimeter always on next to the circuit to make it work. There is probably some beginner mistake I simply overlooked.

Comment: The multimeter is the bottom leg of the voltage divider at the minus input of the opamp. The phototransistor is the top leg. A typical modern multimeter has an input impedance of 10M. You probably don't want to use a resistor that large, try a 100k or 1M in place of the multimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no sort of voltage divider on the -ve input to the OA1.  If the prototransistor leaks any current at all when off, even a few microamps, then the -ve input will be pulled high to 5V all the time.

A typical digital multimeter has a resistance of 10M ohms.  By connecting it, you're creating the missing voltage divider.  So when the phototransistor is off, the -ve input is pulled to ground.

Comment: I added a 40kΩ resistor on inverting and non-inverting inputs of the op-amp and it works now perfectly. Thank you very much for the answer